# Clear Developer Console Test Run Results

Tags: unit-test, developer-console

Being familiar with the Developer console.. Can Any one tell me how to **clear the test run results area in the developer console**

This is the section that I want to clear...

[image: Developer console test results]

Comment: It is possible: Select: Tests > Clear Test Data. Then press F5. Don't worry, your developer console tabs will be the same after refresh.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.

See this Idea on the IdeaExchange (and vote for it):
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kpiZAAQ

Comment: Ok i understand.....but there are any other tools in the market like developer console ?....

Comment: There is the Force.com IDE (Eclipse), or MavensMate (Sublime Text) although these are both offline tools. There is also aside.io but I've never used it myself.